# Filtering results with GeoFirestore and Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, server-side, geofirestore

I am currently filtering some data using [GeoFirestore for Android](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android). By decreasing the radius, of course it is possible to decrease the number of documents retrieved. However, I would like to further filter the same data using the compound queries functionalities provided by Firestore or simply limit the number of reads using `limit()`, in order to 1) avoid downloading/reading documents that are no needed and 2) improve my users' experience in terms of time and resources.

I know this question has been already asked several times (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572432/is-there-a-way-i-can-combine-a-geofirestore-query-with-a-normal-firestore-query)). Nevertheless, Firestore is rapidly evolving—for this reason I would like to ask if there are updates regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library available at https://github.com/mbramwell1/GeoFire-Android

The location of each document is stored using the following formula (a method is provided by the library itself):

degreeMatch = (latitudeDegrees + 90) * 180 + longitudeDegrees

I did a few tests combining a few operators (including limit and array-contains) and it seems to be returning the correct results.